# Complex rails query - unions? sub-select? can I still used named_scope?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, union

Part of why I love Rails is that I hate SQL - I think it's more like an assembly language that should be manipulated with higher level tools such as ActiveRecord.  I seem to have hit the limits of this approach, however, and I'm out of my depth with the SQL.

I have a complex model with lots of sub-records.  I also have a set 30-40 named_scopes that  implement the business logic from the client.  These scopes get chained together conditionally, which is why I have those `joins_` scopes so the joins don't get clobbered.

I've got a couple of them that don't work right, or at least not how the client wants them to work.  Here's a rough idea of the model structure, with a few named scopes (not all needed for the example) that illustrate my approach and indicate my problems.  *(please forgive any syntax errors)*

```
class Man < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wives

  named_scope :has_wife_named       lambda { |n| { :conditions => { :wives => {:name => n}}}}
  named_scope :has_young_wife_named lambda { |n| { :conditions => { :wives => {:name => n, :age => 0..30}}}}
  named_scope :has_yw_named_v2      lambda { |n| { :conditions => ["wives.name = ? AND wives.age <= 30", n]}}
  named_scope :joins_wives         :joins => :wives

  named_scope :has_red_cat          :conditions => { :cats => {:color => 'red'}}        
  named_scope :has_cat_of_color     lambda { |c| { :conditions => { :cats => {:color => c}}}}
  named_scope :has_7yo_cat          :conditions => { :cats => {:age => 7}}
  named_scope :has_cat_of_age       lambda { |a| { :conditions => { :cats => {:age => a}}}}
  named_scope :has_cat_older_than   lambda { |a| { :conditions => ["cats.age > ?", a] }}
  named_scope :has_cat_younger_than lambda { |a| { :conditions => ["cats.age < ?", a] }}
  named_scope :has_cat_fatter_than  lambda { |w| { :conditions => ["cats.weight > ?", w] } }
  named_scope :joins_wives_cats     :joins => {:wives => :cats}
end

class Wife < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :man
  has_many :cats
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :wife
end
```

1. I can find men whose wives have cats that are red AND seven years old

   ```
   @men = Man.has_red_cat.has_7yo_cat.joins_wives_cats.scoped({:select => 'DISTINCT men'})
   ```

   And I can even find men whose wives have cats that are over 20 pounds and over 6 years old

   ```
   @men = Man.has_cat_fatter_than(20).has_cat_older_than(5).joins_wives_cats.scoped({:select => 'DISTINCT men'})
   ```

   But that's not what I want.  I want to find the men whose wives have amongst them at least one red cat and one seven year old cat, which need not be the same cat, or to find the men whose wives have amongst them at least one cat above a given weight and one cat older than a given age.
   *(in subsequent examples, please assume the presence of the appropriate `joins_` and `DISTINCT`)*
2. I can find men with wives named Esther

   ```
   @men = Man.has_wife_named('Esther')
   ```

   I can even find men with wives named Esther, Ruth OR Ada (sweet!)

   ```
   @men = Man.has_wife_named(['Esther', 'Ruth', 'Ada'])
   ```

   but I want to find men with wives named Esther AND Ruth AND Ada.
3. Ha ha, only joking, actually, I need this:  I can find men with wives under 30 named Esther

   ```
   @men = Man.has_young_wife_named('Esther')
   ```

   find men with young wives named Esther, Ruth or Ada

   ```
   @men = Man.has_young_wife_named(['Esther', 'Ruth', 'Ada'])
   ```

   but as above I want to find men with young wives named Esther AND Ruth AND Ada.  Fortunately, the minimum is fixed in this case, but it would be nice to specify a minimum age as well.
4. is there a way to test for an inequality with a hash syntax, or do you always have to revert to `:conditions => ["", n]` - note the difference between `has_young_wife_named` and `has_yw_named_v2` - I like the first better, but the range only works for finite values.  If you're looking for an old wife, I guess you could use `a..100` but then when a wife turns 101 years old she drops off the search. *(hmm. can she cook? j/k)*
5. is there a way to use a scope within a scope?  I'd love it if `:has_red_cat` could use `:has_cat_of_color` somehow, or if there was some way to use the scope from a child record in its parent, so I could put the cat related scopes into the `Wife` model.

I really don't want to do this in straight SQL without using `named_scope`, unless there's something else actually nicer - suggestions for plugins and whatnot greatly appreciated, or direction into the sort of SQL I'll need to learn.  A friend suggested that UNIONs or sub-searches would work here, but those don't seem to be discussed much in the context of Rails.  I don't yet know anything about views - would they be useful? Is there a rails-happy way to make them?

Thank you!

*As I was going to St Ives

I met a man with seven wives

Each wife had seven sacks

Each sack had seven cats

Each cat had seven kits

Kits, cats, sacks, wives

How many were going to St Ives?*

Comment: It's a really interesting question in the abstract. And I understand that your model and scope names are derived from a nursery rhyme. But it's offputting, for me. Wife :belongs_to Man? Seriously?

Comment: yeah, I thought of that when I was writing it, but the poem had popped into my head and I couldn't get rid of it.

Comment: I would like to find a good way to do `UNION`s in named scopes in AR. I know you can do do them in SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've had great results with `named_scope`s like these:

```
named_scope :has_cat_older_than   lambda { |a| { :conditions => ["men.id in ( select man_id from wives where wives.id in ( select wife_id from cats where age > ? ) )", a] } }
```

and

```
named_scope :has_young_wife_named lambda { |n| { :conditions => ["men.id in ( select man_id from wives where name = ? and age < 30)", n] } }
```

I can now successfully do

```
Member.has_cat_older_than(6).has_young_wife_named('Miriam').has_young_wife_named('Vashti')
```

and get what I'm expecting.  These scopes don't require the use of the joins, and they seem to play well with the other styled joins.

w00t!

Commentary elicited on whether this is an efficient way to do this, or if there is a more 'rails-y' way.  Some way to include a scope from another model as an sql subquery fragment could be useful...

Answer (score 2):

I've used construct_finder_sql to accomplish the subselect of one named_scope within another.  It may not be for everyone, but using it allow us to DRY up a couple of named_scopes we used for reports.

```
Man.has_cat_older_than(6).send(:construct_finder_sql,{})
```

Try that in your script/console.

Comment: It took me 7 months to finally understand this, and it is really really handy.  I think it would solve my original problem, and it just untied a similarly knotty bit of trouble.

Pro-tip:
`send(:construct_finder_sql,{:select => 'men.id'}))`

to turn a scope into a string so you exclude records with, e.g.:
`named_scope :excluding_sql, lambda { |sql| {:conditions => "men.id NOT IN (#{sql})"}}`

like this:
`Man.complex_scope_one.exclude_sql(Man.complex_scope_two.send(:construct_finder_sql,{:select => 'men.id'})) )`
 this will exclude complex_scope_two from complex_scope_one

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You used the most native solution for Rails.
Straight SQL will have the same performance so there is no reason to use it.

Comment: I'm not looking for more performance - I'm looking for the query to work properly.  I'd either like to know how to properly structure my query within Rails, or how to write SQL that will do it.